# Mex file for the edison_wrapper_mex.cpp provided by Mr. Bagon’s stuff for the Mean Shift Segmentation is not working in MATLAB 2014a

Tags: c++, matlab

I am Trying to Run the  MEX wrapper for this EDISON code for the mean shift
    segmentation Provided on the website of Mr Shai Bagon in MATLAB 2014a. For
    Running this code I am following the procedure mentioned below.

In MATLAB command window I am typing Following instruction
   ( I have already  installed the Visual Studio 2010)

Step1: >>mex -setup

Step2: selected VC++

Step3: Now trying to run compile_edison_wrapper which is given below

But getting the error:

```
Error using mex
edison_wrapper_mex.cpp
d:\mean shift\edge/BgEdgeList.h : error C4335: Mac file format detected: 
  please convert the source file to either
  DOS or UNIX format
  D:\Mean shift\edison_wrapper_mex.cpp(134) : warning C4018: '<' :
   signed/unsigned mismatch

   D:\Mean shift\edison_wrapper_mex.cpp(168) : warning C4018: '<' : 
   signed/unsigned mismatch
   D:\Mean shift\edison_wrapper_mex.cpp(179) : warning C4018: '<' :  
   signed/unsigned mismatch
   Error in compile_edison_wrapper (line 1)
   mex -O edison_wrapper_mex.cpp ...
```

Comment: Did you try switching the source file to Windows character encoding and Windows line breaks? Any good text editor can change that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the '/' to '\' in file edison_wrapper_mex.h
   This is because the code was possibly written in Mac.
2. Try and compile as instructed. It will give some errors in .h and .cpp files in edges folder. This is because these files have been encoded in UTF-8 format while Windows require it to be UTF-16LE. You could use any editor to recode or copy paste the entire text, you'll notice loss of 'newline' characters. Just hit enter and make it look pleasing. Save the files by same name in edges folder and Voila.
3. I had some error in ambiguous use of pow from math.h in 'edge\BgEdgeDetect.cpp'. Just go to the line number (386) where the error points and make the first argument to double either by explicitly making it double (as I have done below) or typecasting to (double).
   i.e.
   Change:

   ```
   w = pow(2,(-2*WL_))*factorial(2*WL_)/(factorial(WL_-i)*factorial(WL_+i));
   ```

to:

```
    w = pow(2.0,(-2*WL_))*factorial(2*WL_)/(factorial(WL_-i)*factorial(WL_+i));
```

Comment: I can't see how the two "pow" examples for point 3 are different?

Comment: @DavidCoster - Changing the first argument "2" to double "2.0"